# Date sorting format: Day-Month-Year

Tags: date, sort

I have a text file with date value.

Data:

```
01-Sep-21
02-Jan-22
12-Aug-21
24-Dec-21
11-Jul-22
```

How to sort these data from old to new date value?

Answer (score 11):

With the GNU implementation of `sort` and assuming all dates are from the same century¹:

```
<your-file LC_ALL=C sort -t- -k3,3n -k2,2M -k1,1n
```

Where `-t` specifies the field separator, `-k <start>,<end><flags>` specifies where the sort keys start, end and how they should be interpreted / compared via the `<flags>`.

The `n` flag is for numeric comparison, `M` (a GNU extension) for month name or abbreviation comparison (here, assumed to be in English by fixing the locale to `C` where the month names are in English).

So here, the sort keys, are the year first (compared `n`umerically, though lexical comparison would also work as they're always on 2 digits on your sample), then the month abbreviation field (compared as `M`onth), then the day (again compared numerically, though lexical would also work).

With the GNU implementation of `date`, you could also do:

```
date -f your-file +%F | sort
```

Same as:

```
date --iso-8601 -f your-file | sort
```

To convert those dates to the standard YYYY-MM-DD format, which can be sorted lexically as is (at least until 9999-12-31).

For current versions of GNU `date`, from testing, it seems 01-Jan-00 to 31-Dec-69 are 2000-01-01 to 2069-12-31, and 01-Jan-70 to 31-Dec-99 are 1970-01-01 to 1999-12-31.

On non-GNU systems, you can always use a Schwartzian transform / decorate-sort-undecorate approach with:

```
<your-file awk -F- '{printf "%s%02d%s\t%s\n", $3, index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",$2), $1, $0}' |
  sort | cut -f2-
```

And decide on the century cut off date, and match month names case insensitively with:

```
<your-file awk -F- '
  {
    printf "%s%02d%s\t%s\n", \
      $3 + ($3 < 70 ? 2000 : 1900), \
      index("jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,oct,nov,dec", tolower($2)), \
      $1, \
      $0
  }' |
  sort |
  cut -f2-
```

---

<sup>¹ well a century runs from 2001-01-01 to 2100-12-31 for instance, I mean that if there's a `01-Sep-21` and `12-Jan-86` for instance, that means 2021 and 2086 or 1921 and 1986, not 1986 and 2021.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Using Python and dates file `dates.txt`:

```
from datetime import datetime
with open('dates.txt') as f:
    dts = [datetime.strptime(line.rstrip(), '%d-%b-%y') for line in f]
for k in sorted(dts):
    print(k.strftime('%d-%b-%y'))
```

Can also use `dateutil.parser` if you want to parse dates in different syntaxes:

```
from dateutil import parser
with open('dates.txt') as f:
    dts2 = [parser.parse(line) for line in f]
for k in sorted(dts2):
    print(k.strftime('%d-%b-%y'))
```

Both outputs the same, from oldest to newest:

```
12-Aug-21
01-Sep-21
24-Dec-21
02-Jan-22
11-Jul-22
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort dates with `datesort` from [`dateutils`](https://github.com/hroptatyr/dateutils), using `-i, --input-format=` option:

```
datesort -i '%d-%b-%y' infile
```

You can also specify a different locale for the dates e.g.

```
datesort -i '%d-%b-%y' --from-locale=it_IT <<\IN
01-Dic-21
22-Gen-22
12-Ago-21
24-Set-21
11-Lug-22
09-Ott-20
21-Ago-19
IN
```

```
21-Ago-19
09-Ott-20
12-Ago-21
24-Set-21
01-Dic-21
22-Gen-22
11-Lug-22
```